# Deep Learning with Keras MNIST Database Query Why to convert from int to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I am learning Deep Learning with help of book on Deep Learning with Python

Here following code is getting converted into float

```
train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255
```

Can you pl tell me why it is required to convert into Float range (0..1). while original train data was in array of shape (60000, 28, 28) of type uint8 with values in the [0, 255] interval ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you might find your answer here https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/why-do-we-need-floats-for-using-neural-networks?newreg=b2f4364b085d490296ecf1e54e0f3df5

Answer (score 0):

It is most common to use 32-bit precision when training a neural network, so at one point the training data will have to be converted to 32 bit floats. Since the dataset fits easily in RAM, we might as well convert to float immediately.

Comment: Hi @Tushar thanks for your answer, but not understood what is the requirement of converting float ? is it mandatory to have data in float before processing in Neural Network in Keras ?

Answer (score 0):

All the methods or functions in Keras expect the input data to be in default floating datatype (*float32*). Even if you try to train on the data with *float16* or *double* or *any other datatype*, you will get runtime exception something like this:

`RuntimeError: "conv2d_cpu" not implemented for 'Half'`

Hence, the data and model computations happen on *float32*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).